# Add or change comment for MySQL table or column?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin `3.5.1`. I did all the necessary instalation and configuration steps (created the special `phpmyadmin` database and tables, set up the `pma` user etc.). My phpMyAdmin seems to indicate that everything is set correctly.

My problem is I can't see how to add a comment to a table, or to a specific column. Where is that?

Comment: Table comments are in the "operations" tab; column comments are via editing the column.

Comment: What a dumb place to put it, and that's the right answer ;-) Thank you Sam. If you want to add that as an official answer to this question, I'd be happy to award you the points.

Comment: Note that table comments are a function of MySQL, and the special "phpmyadmin" database isn't required for them to work.  For instance, this SQL will apply a table comment (no phpMyAdmin required at all for this to work): `ALTER TABLE  customers COMMENT =  'Customer information';`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Table comments are in the "operations" tab; column comments are via editing the column.

Answer (score 9):

A quick reference or check-list (for phpMyAdmin version `4.0.1`):

a) table comment:

- when creating new table: below columns list, `Table comments` field, next to `Storage Engine`,
- when changing comment for existing table: `Operations > Table options > Table comments`.

b) column comment: always as one of last columns (`Comments`) in add / change columns view.

Note, that while column's comment length is unlimited (very long anyway; managed to add comment with `2000` characters), table's comment length is limited to only 60 characters (not quite much). I don't know, from where does this limitation come from (MySQL or phpMyAdmin), but it is surely odd and should be replaced -- in most cases, you have to write a much more comment for entire table than for one column.

Answer (score 1):

@trejder's answer is perfect for phpMyAdmin. For anyone looking for **table comment** in **MySQL Workbench**: When creating or editing a table, click on the downward arrow next to the table name and schema on the far top right, there you can view/edit the comment.

[image]

You can also view the comment by right-click on the table > Table Inspector, you will find it in the bottom.

[image]